# Endless oscillator

Tags: oscillator, electromagnetism, capacitance, inductance

Can we create an endless oscillator?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fC2NOM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The diodes will only allow a tiny current to move through the tank circuit-> the power loss due to ohmic resistance will be incredibly small and for all practical purposes this could oscillate forever.

The output will be the second circuit below the tank circuit.The costantly varrying current ( even if small ) will create a varrying magnetic field which will induce alternating current to the second circuit.

Note that the Inductor must have a big impendance to compensate for the tiny current.What do you think?

It is assumed that the total voltage of the first circuit doesnt reach the breakdown voltage of any of the diodes.

Comment: Through electromagnetic induction. The inductance of the second circuit is very small so it doesn't affect the first circuit.

Comment: I'm not sure what the diodes are for, but such a circuit will pick up some amount of energy from the electromagnetic noise in the environment. But I wouldn't call it an oscillator; the output will just be filtered noise.

Comment: The diodes exist to limit current in both directions.

Comment: Well, yes, but since they're back-to-back, it will be limited to their reverse leakage current, which is tiny. Effectively open-circuit. It would probably be better to just short them out altogether in order to get the maximum current in the loop.

Comment: Since the current is tiny the power loss is tiny as well!

Comment: In that case, I'm completely missing the point of this thought experiment. Where are you going with this?

Comment: Since we don't work with superconductors, we let a tiny current oscillate to minimise power loss so the oscillation of electric and magnetic fields can happen many many times.

Comment: You can't work with superconductors, so you go to the opposite extreme and make the resistance as high as possible? What kind of logic is that?

Comment: Yes because power loss across a resistor drops with increase in resistance the energy will fade away in the form of heat more slowly more oscillations possible.

Comment: If the current is small, then the energy stored in the inductor (and capacitor) is very small to begin with. So, even if power loss drops with increase in resistance, the initial energy was also very small.

Comment: But at the same time due to the relative high impedance of the inductor the second circuit will have a relatively decent curent.

Comment: Which will cause the second circuit to take away even more energy from the first loop causing the oscillations in the first loop to die down quickly.

Comment: AJN if we have a huge bucket filled with water and there is  a tiny hole will the bucket be emptied quickly?

Comment: AJN the second loop has almost 0 inductance so it's magnetic field will be neglible.

Comment: Second loop has a resistance which dissipates energy it took from the first loop.

Comment: But this is about the energy of the second loop not the energy of the first loop.

Comment: second loop gets energy from the first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110278/discussion-between-ajn-and-maddy-wells).

Answer (score 3):

Maddy, you have a good idea.

However, there is a QUALITY FACTOR we can compute for even simple L+C circuitry

And at a Q of 5 (ratio of XL/R = Xc/R = 5 at the resonant frequency), the voltage drops by 50% over each cycle.

That also means the stored power drops by (0.5)^2 or 4:1 drop.

Now let us suppose your L+C (closed_circuit_loop, so the energy can slosh back and forth between the capacitor and the inductor), rings at 10 cycles per second.

The drop in voltage in one second would be (0.5)^10 or 1/1024 left after one second.

Suppose we charged up the capacitor to 10,000 volts. (this is possible. I recall 10,000 volt capacitors --- inside glass, oil filled --- being shown to the students in high school).

At one second, the capacitor voltage is 10 volts (10,000 / 1,024 to be exact).

At two seconds, voltage is 10/1,024 or about 0.01 volts (10 milliVolts).

At 3 seconds, V = 0.01/1,024 or about 10 microVolts.

At 4 seconds, V = 10uV/1,024 or about 10 nanoVolts.

And 10 nanoVolts is about the random noise voltage across your resistor in the 2nd circuit.

Check into Boltzman noise (aka Johnson noise, or Harry Nyquist noise).

Also read up on Q or bandwidth of LC circuits.

Good question. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't construct this with real components.  If nothing else, you'll never get rid of the effective series resistance of the capacitor.  There is no 100% efficient circuit in real life.

Comment: Capacitors have almost 0 resistance.

Comment: And I don't say it is 100% efficient. 'For all practical purposes the oscillation will continue forever' means that the energy will eventually fade away but after so much time.

Comment: Capacitors don't have almost 0 resistance. Practical capacitors typically have 1 to 10 milliohms depending on capacitor type and construct. And since that is far higher than almost 0, it won't work.

Comment: @MaddyWells _Almost_ 0 is > 0. Even if a circuit sat around and self-oscillated for years, that's fantastically short of 'forever.'

Comment: JYelton we are missing the point here. Theoretically yes it is far shorter than forever but if it needs recharging 1 time in 3 years then it is very practical.

Comment: Justme  it doesn't really matter bcs the resistance of the diode is much bigger than the resistance of the capacitor anyway.